# Macro defining another macro with spaces in its name

Tags: macros, koma-script, expansion

I am trying to use the KOMA-Script command `\newcaptionname` which takes a macro name as its second argument, but I need spaces in it:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\newcaptionname{english}{\namewithoutspaces}{With spaces.}
\newcaptionname{english}{\csname name with spaces\endcsname}{Without Spaces} % fails

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}
    \namewithoutspaces

    \csname name with spaces\endcsname
\end{document}
```

`\namewith` is properly defined, but obviously, the definition of `\csname name with spaces\endcsname` fails. I know that this has something to do with expansion, but I think I still do not fully understand this concept (together with all related commands like `\expandafter`, `\noexpand`, `\edef`, ...).

How do I have to modify

```
\newcaptionname{english}{\csname name with spaces\endcsname}{Without Spaces}
```

to make it work?

Comment: why do you need to define a macro with spaces in its _name_ ? (The `\csname` usage you show does that, but it is hard to see why you need that here?

Comment: The names I have to use in `\newcaptionname` come from a list of predefined keywords which in my case contain spaces.

Comment: I'd normalise your keywords first:-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is hard to see why you would need this, but

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\newcaptionname{english}{\namewithoutspaces}{With spaces.}
\def\tmp{\newcaptionname{english}}
\expandafter\tmp\csname name with spaces\endcsname{Without Spaces} % works

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}
    \namewithoutspaces

    \csname name with spaces\endcsname
\end{document}
```